# Get outer class by member annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a class with custom annotation for one of class field:

```
public class Test {

    @CustomAnnotation
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

I just want to know if it possible to get `Class<Test>` by this annotation? Can't find any suitable api..

```
public Class<?> getOuterClass(CustomAnnotation annotation) {
    ...
}
```

`@CustomAnnotation` is declared as `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, annotation does not store any data about where it was declared.
Also annotation can work just like any normal interface, so someone can implement annotation in class an make instances of it that were never used as annotations.

You need either include that information yourself, by adding parameter to annotation and then using it `@CustomAnn(Test.class)` or when reading annotations just remember and include that information yourself in some other object.